# Memcpy Function crashing in C

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy

I am using memcpy in my program and used it as its syntax. But the function crashes. I read some post here and tried to initialize both my char arrays but I am not getting the problem here . Can anyone please look in it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    char *str_result;
    char *str_dst = NULL;
    str_result = (char *) malloc(100);
    str_dst = (char *) malloc(100);

    str_result = "Action done";
    size_t len = strlen(str_result);
    printf("string length is = %d\n", len);
    memcpy(str_dst, str_result, len);
    str_dst [len] = '\0';
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", str_dst[i]);
    }
    free(str_dst);
    free(str_result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know which line it's crashing on?

Comment: Use `strcpy` instead of assigning the pointers to string literals. And `printf ("string length is = %d\n", strlen);` --> `printf ("string length is = %zu\n", len);`

Comment: No, I am actually trying to open .exe file, but that itself is not opening.

Comment: @Cool Guy: I want to see the correct usage of memcpy, and ya its is "len". Thanks for that . :)

Comment: @learningpal - I assume it probably *would* crash, seeing as you are `free()`ing the address of a string literal. Also, *please* don't cast the return of `malloc()`.

Comment: @learningpal You got that part right. The bug is elsewhere. Simply change `str_result = "Action done";` to `strcpy(str_result, "Action done");`

Comment: Please don't change your code after getting answers and comments as it invalidates them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  str_result = "Action done";
```

After this `str_result` does not point to the block which was allocated by `malloc` . Thus freeing memory not allocated by `malloc` or similar can cause error in program (*one of my favourite statement*).

Use `strcpy` also suggested in comments -

```
strcpy(str_result,"Action done");
```

And while printing `str_dst` -

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", str_dst[i]);   // passing char where char * is expected
}
```

You don't need a loop to print `str_dst` .Simply this will work -

```
printf("%s",str_dst);
```

Corrected code   ([Demo](https://ideone.com/5kTyCU))-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int i;
   char *str_result;
   char *str_dst = NULL;
   str_result =  malloc(100);
   str_dst =  malloc(100);

   strcpy(str_result, "Action done");  // copy string at location where str_result points to 
   size_t len = strlen(str_result);
   printf("string length is = %zu\n", len);
   memcpy(str_dst, str_result, len);
   str_dst[len]='\0';    // manually add null character, memcpy won't add it 
   printf("%s\n", str_dst);

  free(str_dst);
  free(str_result);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I corrected the code as you suggested, and above is the edited version but I am still not able to open the .exe file.

Comment: @learningpal  You should not modify the original code in question . Don't do that ever . It creates confusion for others .

Comment: @learningpal  Please see answer. I have included corrected code.

Comment: ya I got your point of not changing the original question. But I am bit confused that in above answers it has been mentioned that one cannot free the `str_result` but you are freeing it in your code.

Comment: @learningpal  That's because I didn't re-assign pointer .  I copied string at that address using `strcpy`.Pointer still points to memory block allocated by `malloc`.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks a lot. Quite appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

The error is here:

```
free (str_result);
```

After the line `str_result = "Action done";`, `str_result` no longer points to the 100-byte block of memory you reserved, but to the string (`const char*`) `"Action done"`. You can't free this pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Below your corrected code with memcpy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    char *str_result;
    char *str_dst = NULL;
    str_result = (char *) malloc (100);
    str_dst = (char *) malloc (100);

    strcpy (str_result, "Action done");
    size_t len = strlen (str_result);
    printf ("string length is = %zu\n", len);

    memcpy(str_dst, str_result, len+1);

    for (i =0;i<len;i++)
    {
        printf( "%c\n", str_dst[i]);
    }

    free (str_dst);
    free (str_result);

    return 0;
}
```

Error in your code:

1. There is a typo in `str_result` declaration: `,` instead of `;`
2. You must use `strcpy` to copy a string to a `char *`: `strcpy (str_result, "Action done");` not `str_result = "Action done";`
3. `%c` is the format to print chars, not `%s`.
4. If you want to define `len` as `size_t` type you must use `%zu` format for `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

You have the following bugs:

> ```
> str_result = (char *) malloc(100);
> ```

Casting the result of malloc is pointless.

> ```
> str_result = "Action done";
> ```

This is not how you assign strings in C. You must use `strcpy()`. Right now, you create a memory leak. Which is why `free(str_result);` later causes your program to crash, `str_result` is no longer pointing at the allocated memory.

> ```
> printf("string length is = %d\n", len);
> ```

The correct format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`.

> ```
> printf("%s\n", str_dst[i]);
> ```

`str_dst` is a string, not an array of strings. It makes no sense to call it from a loop unless you intend to use `%c` to print it character by character.

Comment: @CoolGuy Ah yeah, fixed. That one is a minor issue compared to the other bugs.

Comment: Is it UB to print a `size_t` with `%d`?

Comment: @Lundin: Can you please explain what is the meaning of "Casting the result of malloc" ?

Comment: @learningpal The cast, `(char*)` in your program, [is useless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @CoolGuy: Yes, it is UB.